# Pagination on custom database-driven blogs?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pagination, blogs

I've been tinkering around with PHP lately and wanted to make my own blog code. I know how to select from the database, where I'll have a table designated for entries.

I just want to know how to select only certain sections of the table based on the `page` GET variable.

Sorry about not having any code, but this is a pretty broad question, and I feel that current code isn't really necessary to answer this question.

**EDIT:** I'm using MySQL.

Comment: @Purmou just tell us which database you're using: MySQL, postgreSQL, SQLite, ... - there are slight syntax differences. I've assumed MySQL because it's popular.

Comment: @stivlo: Yeah, I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MySQL you can use the LIMIT clause. Supposing that your page numbering starts with 1:

```
$pageSize = 10;
$page = abs(intval($_GET["page"]));
if ($page < 1) {
    $page = 1;
}
$startResult = ($page - 1) * $pageSize;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tableName` LIMIT $startResult, $pageSize";
```

One very important thing to do when getting parameters from the outside (hostile) environment is sanitize your inputs. If you don't a malicious user or a web bot, could insert any string in your GET page variable and change your query. This is called SQL injection. Just google for it, you'll find plenty of explanations.

Now since we know that our page variable must be a positive integer, I've first treated it with [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) (Get the integer value of a variable) and then with [abs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) (Absolute value), since we want only positive values. An alternative is using prepared statements (look for PDO).

Comment: Thank you! But would you mind explaining `abs()` and `intval()`? I'm new to PHP so I'd like to understand what I'm learning.

Comment: @Purmou: [`abs`](http://www.php.net/abs) returns the absolute value of its input. [`intval`](http://www.php.net/intval) converts its argument to an integer.

Comment: What if `$_GET['page']` is `0`? You'll end up getting results starting at -10.

Comment: @stivlo: Thanks for the code, I'll try it out tomorrow. So you recommend that I wrap all my GETs in `intval()` (as long as I'm retrieving numbers)?

Comment: absolutely, and `mysql_real_escape()` strings that needs to be used in a query.

Answer (score 0):

```
    I will be like below. You have to do changes according to your code style

<?php
        /*
            Place code to connect to your DB here.
        */
        include('config.php');  // include your code to connect to DB.

        $tbl_name="";       //your table name
        // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
        $adjacents = 3;

        /* 
           First get total number of rows in data table. 
           If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
        */
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
        $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
        $total_pages = $total_pages[num];

        /* Setup vars for query. */
        $targetpage = "filename.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
        $limit = 2;                                 //how many items to show per page
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        if($page) 
            $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
        else
            $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

        /* Get data. */
        $sql = "SELECT column_name FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        /* Setup page vars for display. */
        if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
        $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
        $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
        $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
        $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

        /* 
            Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
            We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
        */
        $pagination = "";
        if($lastpage > 1)
        {   
            $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
            //previous button
            if ($page > 1) 
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">« previous</a>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">« previous</span>"; 

            //pages 
            if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
            {   
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }
            elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
            {
                //close to beginning; only hide later pages
                if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
                {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                    }
                    $pagination.= "...";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
                }
                //in middle; hide some front and some back
                elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                {
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                    $pagination.= "...";
                    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                    }
                    $pagination.= "...";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
                }
                //close to end; only hide early pages
                else
                {
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                    $pagination.= "...";
                    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                    }
                }
            }

            //next button
            if ($page < $counter - 1) 
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next »</a>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next »</span>";
            $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
        }
    ?>

        <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {

            // Your while loop here

            }
        ?>

    <?=$pagination?>


Please make changes according to your code style
```

Comment: Is there no way to shorten this?

Comment: check another answer posted by me

Answer (score 0):

Please do changes as required. you can easily style the way the page navigation looks.

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_GET["start"])){
    $start = $_GET['start'];// To take care global variable if OFF
}else{
    $start  = 0;
}
if(!($start > 0)) { // This variable is set to zero for the first page
    $start = 0;
}

$eu = ($start - 0);
$limit           = 5; // No of records to be shown per page.
$whathis      = $eu + $limit;
$back          = $eu - $limit;
$next          = $eu + $limit;

// to check the total number of records
$query         = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM <tablename> ") or die (mysql_error());
$total_rows     = mysql_num_rows($query);

//select the record with limitation
$query         = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM <tablename> limit $eu, $limit ") or die (mysql_error());

//code for previous
if($back >=0) {
echo "<a href='yourpage.php?start=$back'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>PREV</font></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}

//code for the number of page with links
$i     = 0;
$x    = 1;
for($i=0;$i < $total_rows;$i=$i+$limit){
if($i != $eu){
    echo "<a href='yourpage.php?start=$i'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>$x</font></a> ";
}else { 
    echo "<font face='Verdana' size='4' color=red>$x</font>";
} // Current page is not displayed as link and given font color red

$x    = $x+1;
}
//code for next
if($whathis < $total_rows) {
echo "<a href='yourpage.php?start=$next'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>NEXT</font></a>";
}    
?>
```